# Show that $ABC$ is equilateral if and only if $a+b+c=0$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

In the complex plane let $a,b,c \in \Bbb C^3$ represent the points $A,B,C$ all three different from the origin $O$ . Show that $ABC$ is  equilateral if and only if  $$ a+b+c=0$$
I found this in an exam paper and I'm not even sure if it's correct and I really don't know how to move forward after establishing the obvious characteristics of the equilateral triangle. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}^{3}$.

Comment: 0, 1 and $\frac 12 +i\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ create an equilateral triangle but their sum isn't 0. Maybe they must have the same norm?

Comment: @AlessandroCigna  "A, B, C all three *different from the origin*."

Comment: The statement continues to be false: take the previous three point ant tralsate them by $\frac 14$ on the left.

Comment: All $a+b+c=0$ implies is that it's a triangle with centroid at the origin.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition shoud be $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$, see another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949936/for-a-b-c-in-mathbbc-prove-that-a2b2c2-abbcca-iff-a-b-and-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we need that $|a|=|b|=|c|$ as extra condition otherwise we can find solutions which do not represent equilateral triangle (e.g. $a=1, b=c=-\frac12$).

Assuming $|a|=|b|=|c|$, we have that for an equilateral triangle

- $a=re^{i\theta}$
- $b=re^{i\theta+i\frac {2\pi} 3}$
- $c=re^{i\theta+i\frac {4\pi} 3}$

therefore

$$a+b+c= re^{i\theta}(1+e^{i\frac {2\pi} 3}+e^{i\frac {4\pi} 3})=re^{i\theta}\cdot 0=0$$

For the other direction, assuming wlog, up to scaling and rotation, $a=1 \implies b+c=-1$ that is

- $a=1$
- $b=-\frac12+iy$
- $c=-\frac12-iy$

and since $|b|=|c|=1$ we obtain

$$\sqrt{\frac14+y^2}=1 \implies y^2=\frac34 \implies y=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$$

Comment: It only shows one (easy) direction.

Comment: @JCAA ah ok! I see now the $\iff$, thanks

Comment: I think you're implicitly assuming that $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$ for the reverse direction, whereas the original question does not. Luckily the original question is wrong, and this is one way to salvage it.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes I agree, I add something on that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input! But i must ask why is every number's argument is different from the next by 60° added ? I get that an equilateral triangle has all angles 60° but how does it transfers exactly to the complex argument of the points ?

Comment: @OUCHNA Sorry there is a typo for the first part! I fix that.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment the statement is false in general. But a if you assume that $a, b, c$ have the same norm it become true. In fact WLOG you can assume $a=1$, $b=e^{i\beta} $ and $c=e^{i\gamma} $, this because you can first divide by the norm of $a,b$ and $c$ and then rotating the plan such that $a\to 1$.
Now we have that $1+e^{i\beta}+e^{i\gamma}=0$ that is $\begin{cases} 1+\cos\beta +\cos \gamma=0\\ \sin\beta+\sin\gamma =0\end{cases}$. The second condition means $\gamma +\beta =\pi$ and I'm sure you are able to conclude!