# Geometric significance of the terms of the relation $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$ that holds when complex $a$, $b$, $c$ form an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

It is known (and can be easily shown) that if complex numbers $a, b, c$ form an equilateral triangle on the complex plane, then
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca$$

> **Question**
> Is there a geometric significance/interpretation of
>
> - the squares of each of these numbers, as well their sum (i.e. LHS), and
> - the product of pairs of each of the numbers, as well as their sum (i.e. RHS)?

Comment: Hi @Hypergeometricx, you didn't wish us a new year this time but this is a nice question here :)  I'm also curious for the geometric interpretation of given expression apart from $\sum (a-b)^2 = 0$

Comment: See whether [it helps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2949936/for-a-b-c-in-mathbbc-prove-that-a2b2c2-abbcca-iff-a-b-and-c).

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068254/let-z-1-z-2-and-z-3-be-complex-vertices-of-an-equilateral-triangle-show

Comment: Hi @cosmo5 - thanks for noticing the previous new year puzzles haha. Hope you liked them. Busy with other stuff but might come up with some in the future, you never know. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments and references so far, everyone. The question is specifically about the geometric significance of the terms as shown, rather than that of other rearranged forms.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as sum of squares and than you get three vertices of triangle - three vectors at circular form. Is this a geometrical interpretation that satisfies you?